# How to handle image upload with predefined error handling for form

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to include an optional image upload in my express app, but, with the way I've designed the app, I think it's trying to pass the image name from the body instead of using the separate function I've created for it. Is there any workaround for it to verify the file without digging into the models?

```
posts.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const postId = uuidv1();
  const userId = req.query.userId;
  let checkUser = await User.getById(userId);

  if(checkUser.length === 0) {
    User.create(userId);
  }
  const dateCreated = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB');
  const dateUpdated = dateCreated;
  let bodyValues = [];
  let invalid = false;

  let picUpload;
  if (req.files === undefined || req.files === null) {
    picUpload = 'none';
  } else {
    picUpload = req.files.image;
    picUpload.mv('./images' + picUpload.name);
  }

  Post.fillable_properties.map(function (v) {
    if (req.body[v] === null || req.body[v] === undefined)
      invalid = true;
    else bodyValues.push(req.body[v]);
  });

  bodyValues = [postId, ...bodyValues, picUpload, userId, dateUpdated, dateCreated];

  if (!invalid) {
    const [results, error] = await Post.create(bodyValues);
    if (error.length == 0 && results.affectedRows == 1)
      res.status(201).json(response.prepare(201, results, error));
    else
      res.status(400).json(response.prepare(400, results, error));
  } else {
    res.status(400).json(response.prepare(400, [], [{ "message": "Missing data" }, bodyValues]));
  }
});
```

It sets invalid as true probably because the image is not part of the request body, but I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I worked around it within the client to set the file name to an empty string if there's no image to be uploaded, while not ideal it solves the issue in the meantime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).